# How to display error message as a modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a error massage as a modal boostrap... the message is sent correctly but the partial view load as common page... (no modal)

I need your help to solve this.. :)

```
return RedirectToAction("ShowError", new { sErrorMessage = "Error Message" });
```

**This is my ActionResult 'ShowError'**

```
 public ActionResult ShowError(String sErrorMessage)
    {
        ViewBag.sErrMssg = sErrorMessage;
        return PartialView("ErrorMessageView");
    }
```

**My PartialView 'ErrorMessageView'**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          @ViewBag.sErrMssg
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: message is sent from where ? and where is the code where you tried to show it in a modal dialog ?

Comment: you should try to trigger modal('show') event onload

Comment: You don't need to redirect directly to the partial view, just redirect to the same page where from the request are coming and include sErrMssg to the ViewBag. On the page just check if sErrMssg is not null, and if so, then render partial view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following solution:

1. Instead of using `ViewBag` use `TempData["sErrMsg"]` - using `TempData` retains the value accross the current **and** the subsequent HTTP request.
2. In the controller action - set `TempData["sErrMsg"]` to the required error message if a specific condition is met.
3. In the View - check if the `TempData["sErrMsg"]` has a value (contains an error) and if it does use `Html.RenderPartial("ErrorMessageView", TempData["sErrMsg"]);` to render the partial view as a bootstrap modal popup.

**Controller:**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Save(string name)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            TempData["sErrMsg"] = "Product name cannot be empty";

        return View("Index");
    }

    public PartialViewResult ShowError(String sErrorMessage)
    {
        return PartialView("ErrorMessageView");
    }
}
```

**Index View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("name", null, new { style = "width:500px;" })
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}

@if (TempData["sErrMsg"] != null)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ErrorMessageView", TempData["sErrMsg"]);
}
```

**Partial Error View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Model
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I want...  I tested and it works!!  but have conflics with bootstrap's query from layout... modal it doesn't go to center of the screen..